# Check string var to compile with the datetime format

Tags: php, date-format

I need to pass to my sql raw query an string coming from the user side, of course I need to check for sql injection, since I know the string must compile with the datetime format:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

How can I ensure that i'm receiving a valid `datetime` from a `POST/GET` variable?

**EDIT: The possible duplicate is about date format, im talking about DATETIME format that is different.**

Comment: You can check the _format_ with a regular expression - but that will still not mean the _value_ is valid. But if your only concern is SQL injection, just take the appropriate usual measures against it - if the user inputs a "wrong" format, then they will just not get the result they desired.

Comment: Check out the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php where they have handled different formats of the date. You can handle your case similarly

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using regular expressions in PHP or before POST/GET you can check it via JavaScript.

[example](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

Reg Exp:

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}
```